# Outputting Nokogiri scraped data to webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm currently trying to scrape data using Nokogiri from a webpage. So far, I have been able to successfully scrape title and price information using this code in the controller:

```
@items = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'name')]/a").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
@prices = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'price')]/span[contains(@class, 'price-new')]").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
```

and this code in the view:

```
<% @items.zip(@prices).each do |title,price| %>
<%= title+"  "+price%>
<% end %>
```

But this code for images won't work. (Note that I'm trying to scrape the `<img>` tag):

```
@images = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'image')]/a/img").collect
```

Anything I try to write into the view .erb just comes back with a syntax error. Any idea what I'm missing or should be using in the .erb?

Comment: When you ask for help parsing HTML or XML, it's really important to supply a minimal sample of the data to demonstrate what you're working with. Without it we have to imagine what you're talking about, and that does no good.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure what to include. I'll do that from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a typo there? This:

```
@images = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'image')]/a/img").collect
```

Will just return an `Enumerator`. If that's not a typo then the answer would be that you need to pass a block to `collect`, maybe:

```
@images = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'image')]/a/img").collect { |element| element.attribute("src") }
```

It's not clear what you're doing next with `@images` but this would get you the URLs of each image so you can display them yourself.

Comment: Wow thankyou. This has cleaned up the output amazingly. Apologies for the second question, but do know what I need to do in the .erb to actually make it appear on the webpage? I'm really stuck because `<% @items.zip(@prices).each do |title,price| %>
<%= title+"  "+price%>
<% end %>` works perfectly for the other items, but I can't quite get anything similar to work for img. Apologies, I'm very junior at this...

Comment: If it works then you should accept the answer! For each image (`@images.each do |image_url|`) you want to add an HTML img element with src set to the URL (`<img src="<%= image_url %>">`). Shouldn't need to be a lot more complicated than that.